# How to merge artifacts across jobs for the same stage in Gitlab CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

In Gitlab CI artifacts are segregated based on the jobs which generated them and hence when downloading, you can only download it on a per-job basis.

Is there a way to download all the artifacts, or pass on the artifacts to some other stage and upload from there? Basically some way to merge all the artifacts of a stage.

A possible scenario where it can be needed: Let's say in a stage deploy, I am deploying my project on 10 different servers, using 10 different parallel jobs. Each of these generates some artifacts. However, there is no way to download them all from the UI.

So does anyone know of a workaround? I am not looking for API based solution, but instead UI based or editing the CI yaml file to make it work.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a "final" (package) stage in your pipeline which combines all the artifacts together, using the [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts) syntax.

For example:

```
stages:
  - build
  - package

.artifacts_template:
  artifacts:
    name: linux-artifact
    paths:
      - "*.txt"
    expire_in: 5 minutes

build:linux-1:
  extends: .artifacts_template
  stage: build
  script:
    - touch hello-world-linux-1.txt

build:linux-2:
  extends: .artifacts_template
  stage: build
  script:
    - touch hello-world-linux-2.txt

build:linux-3:
  extends: .artifacts_template
  stage: build
  script:
    - touch hello-world-linux-3.txt

package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - echo "packaging everything here"
  needs:
    - build:linux-1
    - build:linux-2
    - build:linux-3
  artifacts:
    name: all-artifacts
    paths:
      - "*.txt"
    expire_in: 1 month
```

Comment: This solution works, however, it still isn't elegant. In the CI/CD page, if you try to download artifacts, it will give you 4 options. 3 for each of the build jobs, and one for package job. More so, the files are effectively being duplicated and kept across two different jobs.

Comment: I've updated my answer. A work-around is to have the jobs artifacts expire a lot sooner than the final job, ie 5 minutes, or as low as you want it. This should remove the 3 build job options and only give you the one job to download via the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parallel:matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-a-one-dimensional-matrix-of-parallel-jobs) to trigger a job multiple times, and then collect artifacts in another job.

For example:

```
deploystacks:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - bin/deploy --target $PROVIDER
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROVIDER: [aws, ovh, gcp, vultr]
  environment: production/$PROVIDER
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - result/$PROVIDER
collectArtifacts:
  stage: collect
  script:
    - processArtifacts <[aws, ovh, gcp, vultr]>
  needs:
    - job: deploystacks
      artifacts: true
```

The above example will create deployStacks job for each of the provider defined in PROVIDER.